# Drag and drop makes selected item shift to the left?

Tags: linux, debian, multiple-monitors, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

I have quite a strange problem.

When I select an icon and want to drag and drop it, it's being shifted to left for exactly the width of left monitor.

I believe there is some problem with my configuration of X, so I'm attaching xorg.conf too.

Other important info: OS is Debian wheezy with nVidia drivers from nvidia.com (not from repos.) and with upgrade from wheezy-backports

Here is xorg.conf:

(one monitor is turned for 90 degrees)

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 900 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer P238HL"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer V193W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVS 5400M"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVS 5400M"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT: 1680x1050 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportin=1920x1080, viewportout=1920x1080+0+0}"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-4: 1440x900 +0+0 {rotation=90}"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Here is how it looks while hold down a click on icon:

[image]